# Combing a list of unequal data.frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine a list of unequal data.frames; the obvious `do.call(rbind, df.lst)` fails but the real problem is padding it out with `NA`s.

```
df.lst <- list(A=data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(5,4),d=c(2,3),e=c(1,1),f=c(1,2),g=c(1,2)),
               B=data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,2),d=c(2,3)),
               C=data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(4,3),d=c(1,2),e=c(1,3))
               )
```

I can see that I need to find the maximum number of columns in the longest data.frame; I can do this with the following code,

```
max(sapply(df.lst,ncol))
```

but after that I'm stuck.  It is suggested that it is possible to index over the list and this automatically fills it with `NA`s.

Once I have the padded list, I anticipate a simple `do.call()` as described earlier.  (I'm trying to keep the answer to base R and although there are many similar questions I can't seem to find an answer to this precise one).

Comment: Try `library(data.table); rbindlist(df.lst, fill=TRUE)` or `bind_rows(df.lst)` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to stick with base R, you can do something like this:

```
### Get all the columns names
col <- unique(unlist(sapply(df.lst, names)))
col
## [1] "a" "b" "d" "e" "f" "g"

### Fill the missing columns with NA
df.lst <- lapply(df.lst, function(df) {
  df[, setdiff(col, names(df))] <- NA
  df
})

### Then Bind it
do.call(rbind, df.lst)
##     a b d  e  f  g
## A.1 1 5 2  1  1  1
## A.2 2 4 3  1  2  2
## B.1 1 3 2 NA NA NA
## B.2 2 2 3 NA NA NA
## C.1 1 4 1  1 NA NA
## C.2 2 3 2  3 NA NA
```

Comment: what does the 'df' immediately after the NA do?

Comment: You need to return the changed `data.frame` (imputed with NA) at the end of the function call if you want `lapply` to modify each `data.frame` as you want it to do.

Comment: It works for my fake data set but not my real data set, do I need to ask a new question with a dput?

Answer (score 6):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df.lst)
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(df.lst, fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
library(plyr)
ldply(df.lst,data.frame)

  .id a b d  e  f  g
1   A 1 5 2  1  1  1
2   A 2 4 3  1  2  2
3   B 1 3 2 NA NA NA
4   B 2 2 3 NA NA NA
5   C 1 4 1  1 NA NA
6   C 2 3 2  3 NA NA
```

If needed you can remove the first column :

```
df<-ldply(df.lst,data.frame)
df[,-1]

a b d  e  f  g
1 1 5 2  1  1  1
2 2 4 3  1  2  2
3 1 3 2 NA NA NA
4 2 2 3 NA NA NA
5 1 4 1  1 NA NA
6 2 3 2  3 NA NA
```